# Processing function not working as intended

Tags: processing, selection-sort

I've implemented a selection sort algorithm in Processing 3.0 and I would like to display the bars as they are being sorted. The code is as follow:

```
ArrayList<Bar> sort() {
int smallest;

for (int i = 0; i < sortedBars.size(); i++) {
  smallest = indexOfMinimum(i);
  swap(sortedBars, smallest, i);

  background(0);

  for (int i2 = 0; i2 < sortedBars.size(); i2++) {
    sortedBars.get(i2).display(i2, 255);
  }
}

return sortedBars;}
```

however, this code only displays some bars in the initial state and the final state, skipping everything in between.

On the other hand, if I use a similar function, but that runs only one time

```
ArrayList<Bar> sort(int i) {
  int smallest = indexOfMinimum(i);
  swap(sortedBars, smallest, i);

  return sortedBars;}
```

And then call it multiple times inside draw() function, it works just fine.
Am I doing something wrong?

edit: Forgot to mention, this is the display function:

```
void display(int position, color col) {
stroke(col);
line(position, height, position, height - barSize);}
```

Also, the Bar class has an attribute called barSie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how Processing is intended to work.

Processing is double-buffered, which means that it draws everything to an off-screen buffer before it copies that buffer to the screen. Usually that's a good thing, as it makes animations smoother. But like you've discovered, it prevents the "in-between" frames from showing.

To solve your problem, there are two approaches I can think of:

Option one: instead of using a `for` loop to do your iteration, use each call to the `draw()` function as one "step" in your algorithm. That would allow you to show one step per frame.

Option two: instead of drawing to the screen, draw each step of your algorithm to its own buffer, which you can create using the `createGraphics()` function. Either save the frames to disc, or in their own data structure. Then when the algorithm completes, you'll have a set of frames that you can then display.

Which approach you take really depends on you and what your end goal is. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using your "option one" approach.